# Representation of fixdt in generated C code

Tags: c#, matlab

How will a signal in simulink with datatype, `fixdt(0,16,0.01,0)` be represented in C# if I generate the code out of it? As far as i know, C# does not have any similar dataype. So will it just take as uint16 (unsigned short)? If so, how will it process the decimal part?

P.S I dont have the code generation toolbox so I wont be able to try this on my own.

Comment: Did you mean to use the c# tag, instead of the c tag?

Comment: Don't you want the parameter list of a method?